# Android studio uses different github account username while pushing

Tags: android-studio, github

I have two accounts ***github.com/Balaj-Manogar*** for java projects and ***github.com/balaji-manogar-cs/*** for android projects

I am using Android studio(Mac) to share my projects i configured  **github.com/balaji-manogar-cs/** as my github account in CVS-> github

When i push to remote i am getting following error as of my knowledge it uses other github account user name while pushing and not able to fix to push to configured github account

I configured user.name and user.email and also tried with command line by changing remote but not able to solve

**Android Studio creates repository in the account but returns 403 while pushing branch**

*remote: Permission to balaji-manogar-cs/GitTest3.git denied to Balaj-Manogar.*

*fatal: unable to access 'github.com/balaji-manogar-cs/GitTest3/': The requested URL returned error: 403*

[Android Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqP7E.png)

Comment: No issue on windows but problem only appears on mac Android Studio 1.5